# Integrating Paypal with Flask

Tags: python, flask, paypal

Please, I've been trying to integrate paypal with flask. I've read the docs and basically all guides I've searched out for are outdated.
I copied the checkout code [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/)
then updated my key but yet, it loads but then keeps loading till forever.
And please I work only with Python, so I guess it's throwing an error of returning promise... but i'm not really sure of what to do. Please I need help.

Answer (score 0):

I am learning python too and doing same paypal integration.
Right now I am on a stage that payment works.

In sandbox of paypal you set two types of accounts: business and personal.
In Business you integrate it with your app by clicking on three dots ... . This will open parameters and on top, select API Credentials.
Inside API Credentials on a bottom, select your app-name (that you have created)
Then in a new window check your Client ID. (copy it)

Replace test with your Client ID in html code (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/):

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=TEST&currency=USD"></script>
```

It should work.
But now my question is ... how to get inside my route in flask/python some details from that payment? Successful or not etc

Comment: I did that but it still didn’t work. It just keeps showing the padlock and spinning nonstop

Comment: Thank you, I think I just fixed it. Had to do everything afresh.

Comment: Please were you able to find a way to getting the details??

Comment: Yes. You need to capture a payment order. I made a blog post. It requires few additional code snippets. You can read it here: https://medium.com/@andrii.gorshunov/paypal-flask-integration-python-2022-1c012322801d . I hope stackoverflow will pass it.

Answer (score 0):

It keeps loading in a new screen (with paypal window), right?
Just switch back to your original screen. Yuu will see a javascript alert message on top, with payment status. Once you click ok, your other window with padlock will disappear too.

Comment: Thank you, I think I just fixed it. Had to do everything afresh.